# ruby : Passing argument to ERB templated file appened to an other file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I need to append to an existing coffee script some lines generated for a given `class_name`. I'm using `ERB` to template the file (assets/javascripts/routes.js.coffee.erb) and then to append to my file; but I couldn't find a solution to pass the argument to the template. So I'm still having the error that `class_name` is not initialized. Any idea ?

I have this lines in my generator

```
# my controller
if File.readlines(tmp_file).grep(/#{class_name.tableize}/).size <= 0 then
  open(tmp_file, 'a') { |f|
    f.puts ERB.new(File.read("#{files_origin}/assets/javascripts/routes.js.coffee.erb")).result
  }
```

And my template file :

```
# assets/javascripts/routes.js.coffee.erb
# <%= class_name.tableize %>
$stateProvider.state('<%= class_name.tableize %>', { 
  # state for showing all <%= class_name.tableize %>
  url: '/<%= class_name.tableize %>',
  templateUrl: '<%= class_name.tableize %>/index.html',
  controller: '<%= class_name.camelize(:upper) %>ListCtrl'
}).state('view<%= class_name.camelize(:upper) %>', { 
  #state for showing single <%= class_name.camelize(:upper) %>
  url: '/<%= class_name.tableize %>/:id/view',
  templateUrl: '<%= class_name.tableize %>/show.html',
  controller: '<%= class_name.camelize(:upper) %>ViewCtrl'
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found it :p

The only thing was to add the [binding](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-i-result) option to allow ERB to use my existing `class_name` variable.

```
 # my controller
if File.readlines(tmp_file).grep(/#{class_name.tableize}/).size <= 0 then
  open(tmp_file, 'a') { |f|
    f.puts ERB.new(File.read("#{files_origin}/assets/javascripts/routes.js.coffee.erb")).result(binding)
  }
```

It now appends the interpreted code to my file. For example when I call my generator to create `livres`, it appends this :

```
# app/assets/javascripts/routes.js.coffee
# livres
$stateProvider.state('livres', { 
  # state for showing all livres
  url: '/livres',
  templateUrl: 'livres/index.html',
  controller: 'LivreListCtrl'
}).state('viewLivre', { 
  #state for showing single Livre
  url: '/livres/:id/view',
  templateUrl: 'livres/show.html',
  controller: 'LivreViewCtrl'
})
```